# Decrease size of hitboxes for a sprite in PixelPAD

Tags: collision-detection, sprites, python

I need to make the hitboxes of spikes smaller, so that it's not impossible for the player to get through. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm browsing the documentation for PixelPAD, and not finding methods to change the hitbox of a sprite separate from the sprite's rendered width and height. Have you considered splitting your spikes into two objects, a small one that handles hits, and then the rest of the image on an object that does not trigger spike collision code?